# Java checking array contents

Tags: java, arrays

The problem I am having is using `.contains()` for an array. This is my current line of code:

`if (strings[i].contains(symbol) = true){`

`strings[]` is an array that stores user inputted data, the error message i get for this is "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". I understand what this means, my question is, can I use one string from the array when using `.contains()` or am I going about this the wrong way?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need `==` to check for equality.  `=` is assignment.

Comment: And to answer your question, you can only use `.contains()` on individual strings. Arrays don't have `.contains()` method.

Comment: And since you're comparing values between boolean values, `==` is completely redundant and leads to nothing but potential problems such as what you're experiencing right now. @Codebender the OP is using the `contains()` method correctly in his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
strings[i].contains(symbol) = true
```

is an assignment because of the `=`. You probably mean

```
strings[i].contains(symbol) == true
```

and, because the left hand side is a boolean,

```
strings[i].contains(symbol)
```

is already sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is, can I use one string from the array when using .contains()

If you read the Java API for String (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), `contains()` is a method from String class.
By knowing that, you can use `.contains()` on a single String element / a String variable.

```
String str = "abc";
str.contains(symbol);     //This is ok.

String[] strs = {"abc", "def"};
str[0].contains(symbol);  //This is ok too.
```

Both of the above are allowed, because both are `String`.

```
String[] strs = {"abc", "def"};
str.contains(symbol);    //This is wrong!
```

---

One more thing which you should have noted by now in your codes is:

- When comparison, use `==` and not single `=`
- And when comparing strings or objects, use `.equals()`

---

Of course, you can also write it as:

```
if(strings.[i].contains(symbol))     //if this statement is true
if(!strings.[i].contains(symbol))    //if this statement is not true
```

instead of

```
if(strings.[i].contains(symbol) == true)     //if this statement is true
if(strings.[i].contains(symbol) == false)    //if this statement is not true
```